# Multi file upload validaiton javascript if statement not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, loops, if-statement

Trying to add validation for my files to see if the files being uploaded exceed 5MB, however it doesnt alert if the file is over 5MB, Can anyone see what is wrong with my validaiton in my IF statement? This is a multi file upload which works fine but the validation doesnt

```
function makeProgress(number){   
          var url = getRelativeURL("web/fileUpload");   
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('number', number);
          fls = document.getElementById("attachmentFileUploadInput").files; //number of files... 
          console.log(fls);
          for(j=0;j<fls.length;j++){
              if (fls.size > 5000000) //5MB
            {
                  console.log('error');
                  alert('file to big');
            }
              else
                  {
              formData.append('files[]', fls[j]);  //note files[] not files
              $.ajax({
                  url : url,
                  data : formData,
```

Comment: fls is an array of files? so, to get size of each indivial file:`fls[j].size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check the size of the current file. Change

```
if (fls.size > 5000000) //5MB
```

to

```
if (fls[j].size > 5000000) //5MB
```

One more think. You don't declare `j` in your function and therefore it is in the global scope which can break things because it can be manipulated in some other parts of your code. You can declare it like this:

```
var j;
for(j=0;j<fls.length;j++){
```